# Compiler not giving error for alternative name for 'default' case in switch

Tags: c, switch-statement

I found the below code while googling.

```
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    switch(a)
    {
        case '1':
           printf("ONE\n");
           break;
        case '2':
           printf("TWO\n");
           break;
        defa1ut:
           printf("NONE\n");
     }
     return 0;
  }
```

The compiler is not giving an error even if the 'default' is replaced by any other name.
It is simply executing the program and exiting the program without printing anything.

Would anyone please tell me why the compiler is not giving an error on default case ? when it is not spelled as 'default'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a normal (goto) label.

You could do this, for example:

```
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    switch(a)
    {
        case '1':
           printf("ONE\n");
           break;
        case '2':
           printf("TWO\n");
           break;
        defa1ut:
           printf("NONE\n");
     }
     goto defa1ut;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: :Thank you for the answer. So, that means I can enter to this goto label from other parts of the program,even if the label is within a switch statement

Comment: 1/ That won't act the same, it will print `NONE` until the cows come home. 2/ It's particularly bad programming that you appear to have convinced the OP to use. Better to just explain _why_ this happens and put forward the solution of spelling `default` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you use GCC, add `-Wall` to the options.

Your statement is a valid statement, it declares a label.
If you use -Wall, GCC will warn you about the unused label, not more.

Comment: Actually, it might warn if the type of the switch selector is an enum and not all cases of the enum are handled.